# Is there something equivalent to this in C++

Tags: c++

Lets say that you have two classes defined as such:

```cpp
class A {
    double a;
    A(double d)
    {
        a = d;
    }
};

class B {
    double b;
    B(A a)
    {
        b = exp(a.a);
    }
};
```

Then lets say that you wish to have a main that does the following:

```
A a(3.14);
B b(a);

print(b.b) // 23.1......

a.a = 2.71

print(b.b) // 15.1......
```

I am not sure what to call this other than something like dynamic evaluation or something. If this is possible using C++, what is it called?

I am sorry for the vagueness in this question, but I have no idea how to describe it any better.

Comment: What do you think is "dynamic" about this?  You are changing an object directly which is also used indirectly inside of another object.

Comment: How about references?

Comment: You're asking about polymorphism!

Comment: So you want the value of b.b to be dynamic, essentially always the value of exp(a.a)? You could easily do this by storing a pointer to the A object instead of the value of exp(a.a) at the time of construction. Then using a function to deference that value and perform the exp() operation and return the result.

Comment: what I'm looking for would not require evaluation after `a.a` is given a new value. Preferably it would print then assign the new value, then print again.

Comment: You have to reevaluate `a.a` - How else do you plan to determine the value of `exp(a.a)` if the value of  `a.a` is changing? You could store a reference to `a.a` in class B, or even a reference to an A object itself, but you will need a method to calculate `exp(a.a)` as it changes. I wrote up a solution but it's essentially the same as the answer someone just posted.

Comment: Well... that's exactly what I asked if it was possible to do in some sort of way. As such, the answer is no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you're asking based on your refining comments is not possible. There is no way to update the value `b.b` when `a.a` changes, without recalculating `std::exp(a.a)`. Thus you need a function call to do that, and pretty much the best way you can do that is how @ÖöTiib has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to store reference of `A` in `B`. Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct A 
{
    double value;
};

class B
{
    A& a_;
public:
    B(A& a) :a_(a) { }
    double value() {return std::exp(a_.value);}
};

int main()
{
    A a{3.14};
    B b(a);

    std::cout << b.value() << '\n'; // 23.1039

    a.value = 2.71;

    std::cout << b.value() << '\n'; // 15.0293
}
```

Comment: This isn't it as it performs the function call when what I'd like is to just retrieve the value. I am aware of how to use pointers and how to dereference attributes as I have experience with C. That is why I called it dynamic.

Comment: @Ohunter the value isn't something that is constant. Even in a language that "supports" the behavior you are talking about, the value *must* technically be recalculated since it is the result of a function, not a variable instance.

Comment: In some languages, such as C#, attributes can have get/set routines which can be altered to perform anything a function can do. Sometimes this is useful for treating the results of functions as standalone variables. This type of behavior would allow what you want, but it definitely is technically a function call. You cannot do this in C++, however.

Comment: I was going to post essentially the same answer but Oo Tiib beat me to it. This is also in my opinion the closest way to do what the OP is asking in the C++ language.

Comment: You want the value of b to be always exponent of value of a regardless of when a changes and so value of b is function of value of a in mathematical sense. Why you need that to be hidden somehow?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking about is called ["reactive programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), and in paticular reactive properties. Reactive programming is not built into C++, but there are [various](https://github.com/tower120/reactive) [libraries](http://reactivex.io/RxCpp/) out there to support the reactive paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

I am only a begginer, but this is how I would approach it.

Let me assume that you want strictly what is written inside your main, and that your `print` does nothing else but printing.

With these assumption, `print(b.b)` has no way to know that `a.a` has been modified. In C++ the [accessing to a member object cannot be overloaded](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access). Therefore, we cannot add the functionality of checking the current value of `a.a`.

The only places that I see in which you could introduce that check are in `print(...)` or in `a.a = 2.71`.

We can add this functionality in `operator=(const double&)` of the member `a` of the instance `a` of `A`. For this, this object needs to know which instance `b`, or instances, of `B` to 'tell' that it was updated. The member `a` of `A` should be a type that behaves like a `double` but we will provide our own `operator=(...)`.

For example

`A.h` can be

```
#pragma once

class B;

class UpdatableDouble {
public:
    double d;
    B* myb; // We will tell, in this example, only one B that it needs to update.
    UpdatableDouble(const double& d) : d(d), myb(nullptr) {};
    operator double() {
        return d;
    };

    const double& operator=(const double& d);

    // Add, as needed, the rest of the behavior of double.
};

class A {
public:
    UpdatableDouble a;
    A(const double &d) : a(d) {};
};
```

`B.h` can be

```
#pragma once

#include <cmath>

class A;

class B {
public:
    double b;
    B(A& a) : b(exp(a.a)) {
        a.a.myb = this;
    }
    void update(const double& d) {
        b = exp(d);
    }
};
```

and then in the `Main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

const double& UpdatableDouble::operator=(const double& otherd) {
    d = otherd;
    myb->update(d);
    return d;
};

void print(double& d) {
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
};

int main() {
    A a(3.14);
    B b(a);

    print(b.b); // 23.1......

    a.a = 2.71;

    print(b.b); // 15.1......

    std::string wait;
    std::cin >> wait;
    return 0;
}
```